# Компактное условие [Y/n] на СИ

Tags: linux, c, gcc, условия

CИ изучаю недавно поэтому нужна помощь. Возможно ли записать подобное условие в СИ более менее компактно, так как возможны 4 варианта ответа `[YyДдNnНн]`, и не очень хотелось бы размазывать это на 4 `if else` или `case`

Пример моей реализации на Python:

```
while True:
        chois = input("Сканирование завершено, отправлять результат на почту? [Y/n] ")
        try:
            print(0 <= "YyДдNnНн".index(chois) < 3 and "Отправка письма...\n" or "Результат сканирования сохранен в файл\n")
            # Отправка письма с файлом
            send()
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Неверный ответ")
            break
```

P.s.
Буду рада креативным вариантам)

Comment: `н` в одной раскадке это `y` в другой - у меня так apt два раза систему сломал)

Comment: по коду на питоне есть замечание `x and "a" or "b"` лучше заменить на `"a" if x else "b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно ли записать подобное условие в СИ более менее компактно

Если такой *switch* противоречит Вашим эстетическим чувствам, то можно записать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

char responce[32];

    while (1) {
        printf("Закончить цикл? ");
        scanf("%s", responce);
        if (strtok(responce, "YyДд") == NULL) break;
        printf("Продолжаем работу!\n");
    }
}
```

Не знаю, как в винде, но в люнихе проверил - работает и с латиницей и с кириллицей.

Comment: Ужасно, во-первых многобайтовые кодировки не сработают, во-вторых, бесконечный цикл — плохая практика на любом языке программирования (есть некоторые исключения, но явно не здесь), в-третьих, использование `scanf()` на стек...

Comment: @0andriy *многобайтовые кодировки не сработают* - правда?! Охренеть... А у меня вот как-то сработали... Наверное, у меня какой-то неправильный люних! *бесконечный цикл — плохая практика* - Вам шашечки нужны, или ехать? *использование scanf() на стек* - скажите, Вам делать абсолютно нечего?

Comment: Чем выше рейтинг, тем выше хамство и количество персональных атак. Такой русский дивный мир! Вы бы разобрались вначале в проблемах и граблях, которые выдаёте за ответ.

Comment: @0andriy, у него респонс 32 байта - туда вледет и однобайтный и 2хбатный символ и ещё конец строки в придачу.

Про сканф на стек можно подробней, интересно. Статически занятая память в целых 32 байта это большая проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```c
char c;

...

switch(c)
{
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
    case 'Д':
    case 'д':
    {
        ... // send email
    } break;
    default:
    {
        ... // save to file
    } break;
}
```

Ну например вот так.

---

P.S. Так не сработает с не 8-битной кодировкой, т.к. символ кириллицы занимает 2 байта.

Comment: это с каких пор аскии кодировка имеет двухбайтовые символы? 7 бит - да, 8 - да, но не два байта. Или у Вас особая машина, с 4 битовыми байтами?

Comment: Внизу ответа пост скрипт стоит:)

Comment: @KoVadim, справедливости ради **us-ascii** даже 8 бита не имеет.

Comment: @ヒミコ, Подскажите пожалуйста,  где почитать про двухбайтовые коды ASCII?

Comment: он имел ввиду UTF-8 и UCS-2